# regex validating a time value or a list of time values

Tags: regex, perl

I need a regex, which matches a single time value as well as lists of time values in the format hhmm[, hhmm] like for example:

"1245" or "0056, 1034,2355"

I am not so good with regex.. I thought this would do it:

```
(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))[0-5][0-9](,[ \t]*(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))[0-5][0-9])*
```

single time values are validated correctly, but if I try lists of times, every number behind the comma is accepted. It matches also "1235, 4711".
Can someone give me a hint what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pat = qr/(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9])[0-5][0-9]/;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^$pat(,\s*$pat)*$/) {
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
1245
0056, 1034,2355
1034,2455
```

Comment: Thank you cdtits, that works perfectly!
@dave: To be honest, i do not fully understand the expression above, but i tried it and it is also working for hhmm:)

Comment: @user1542785 I mean that strings beginning with `,` (like `",1234"`) match.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `^` to instruct the regular expression to match *from the beginning of the line*.

The following regex should work.

```
^([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9](,\s*([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9])*$
```

[Try it yourself](http://regexr.com?31jq5)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is more readable regexp and it should work.

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    if( /
         ^(
            (
                ((0|1)\d)|(2[0-3]) #regex for hour (the first number may be 0, 1, or 2
                                   #if 0 or 1, the second number can be from 0 to 9
                                   #if 2, the second number can be from 0 to 3                 
            )
            [0-5]\d                #regex for minutes (the first number 
                                   #can be from 0 to 5, second from 0 to 9)
          )
          (
            ,\s*                   #comma required 
                                   #the separator may be, or may not be
            (
                ((0|1)\d)|(2[0-3])
            )
            [0-5]\d
          )*$
        /x ) {
        print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is basically fine except that it looks for the pattern *anywhere* inside the target string. That means any string that contains a single valid time will match. You must add beginning and end of string anchors `^` and `$` to force the entire string to match the pattern.

You will find it clearer and easier to code regular expressions if you first write a common sub-expression and then use it like a subroutine. It also helps to use the `/x` modifier so that you can use whitespace to lay out the expresion more clearly.

For instance, this matches a single time string

```
/ ( [0-1][0-9] | 2[0-3] ) [0-5][0-9] /x
```

and you can go on to substitute that twice in the main expression.

It is also better to use non-capturing parentheses like `(?: ... )` unless you really want to capture the substring into `$1`, `$2` etc.

Take a look at this program and see what you think

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $time = qr/(?: (?: [0-1][0-9] | 2[0-3] ) [0-5][0-9] ) /x;

while (<DATA>) {
  print if /^ $time (?: ,[ \t]* $time )* $/x;
}
__DATA__
1245
0056, 1034,2355
1235, 4711
0000,1111
```

**output**

```
1245
0056, 1034,2355
0000,1111
```

Answer (score -1):

This regexp must work:

```
/^(\d+)(, ?\d+)*$/
```